# Automated backreferences between taxonomies

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Talking about DRUPAL 7, I've found some modules that manage automated backreferences between content types, but these are based on nodereference fields: i need something based on TERMREFERENCE.

I'll try to explain better:

I've a vocabulary (i'm talking about taxonomies, NOT content types) and I've added a termreference field type pointing to the same vocabulary. The scope is to have a "see also related terms" feature when someone is viewing a taxonomy term page.

What I need is a backreference between terms, so, when I add a term B as term reference on term A, automatically term A is also attached to term B as termreference itself:

term A -> Term B

Automatically I need a term back reference:

Term B -> Term A

How can this be done?

Thank you very much!

MXT